# Redirection to Admin Customer Edit (with key) from a frontend controller

Tags: admin, customer, redirect, ce-1.6.2.0, key

I'm trying to make a redirection from one of my module to Admin > Manage Customer > Edit.

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/customer/edit/", array("id"=>$customer_id)));
```

The URL called seems to be good, with a url key. But this URL leads to a 302 response and auto-redirect me to the dashboard.

In fact it seems that the generated URL is different from the real URL : the keys are not the same for both of them, which explains why I'm redirected I guess.

If I disable the keys in URL from admin, the redirection is ok.

Can you help me with this problem ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The link is from an admin page or from frontend?

Comment: From the frontend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [How can I generate an admin link from a frontend controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157765/how-can-i-generate-an-admin-link-from-a-frontend-controller)

Short answer: you can't, but if you create a admin controller that will act like a proxy to get the url key then do the redirect (since you can disable the validation  of admin url using `$_publicActions`).

```
class MagePal_ProxyCustomerRedirect_Adminhtml_RedirectController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_publicActions = array('redirecttocustomer');

    public function redirecttocustomerAction()
    {
        // get the customer id pass by your observer (url key)
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/customer/edit/", array("id"=>$customer_id)));
```

In your observer

```
  Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/redirecttocustomer/edit/", array("id"=>$customer_id)));
```

See `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

```
protected function _validateSecretKey()
{
    if (is_array($this->_publicActions) && in_array($this->getRequest()->getActionName(), $this->_publicActions)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!($secretKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME, null))
        || $secretKey != Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```